# Are any results known on the combinatorics of proof theory?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-theory, natural-deduction

Given a system of natural deduction, for example, say $\phi$ is a metavariable, it seems to me that there are only two valid proofs (up to the usual equivalence of proofs, i.e. $\beta \eta$ equivalence) of $\phi \wedge \phi \to \phi \wedge \phi$, (the one which swaps components, and the identity, speaking in terms of the Curry-Howard correspondence) and I expect that in general, any propositional formulae without quantifiers should have finitely many proofs. This leads to several questions:

> Given a proposition in some system of natural deduction without quantifiers, are there only finitely many non-equivalent proofs? Is there a simple combinatorial method for determining the number of inequivalent proofs of a given proposition?
>
> Given a proposition in a system of natural deduction with quantifiers, are there ever infinitely many non-equivalent proofs?

Of course, the first question is an extension of the very-non trivial question of consistency: (How many proofs are there of $\bot$? -- exactly $0$) And I suspect it might be feasible to study via similar methods, such as the sub-formula property, but I was wondering whether or not this has been done in the literature, and similarly for the second question.

Comment: Can you bound the number of ways in which you can rewrite a propositional tautology?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi What do you mean by "rewrite"? Do you mean to reformulate a propositional tautology as an equivalent one? I think that is different from my question, though perhaps related. The question of exactly how they are related I think adds to my question, but I would expect that if $\phi \iff \psi$, then the number of inequivalent proofs of $\phi$ should be the same as the number of inequivalent proofs of $\psi$.

Comment: If in a proof, I first rewrite $\phi$ as (an equivalent) $\psi$ and then prove $\psi$ is a tautology, I get a proof for $\phi$ being a tautology.  Now I pick another equivalent $\psi'$ and repeat the process.  Do you consider these two proofs equivalent?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi That depends on the details of your deduction from $\phi$ to $\psi$. By "the usual equivalence of proofs" I mean that they have the same $\beta \eta$ normal form. (I'll edit my question so that's clearer)

Comment: Also, I should not that what I said about equivalence in my comment is clearly false, at least in the prescense of $\top$, but perhaps there is some other notion of propositional equivalence so that if $\phi \equiv \psi$ then $\phi$ has the same number of inequivalent proofs as $\psi$ (perhaps a notion similar to type equivalence).